# Formatting input in C++ in grid like fashion

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, format

Working on a 2D array Sudoku program where I want the user input to be separated by spaces instead of having each input be line by line. This would make it easier for the user to see what they are inputting any ideas? Wanting it to be 9 numbers by 9 lines instead of line by line.  current code:

```
int main()

{

int grid[N][N];

//Input

    std::cout << "Enter a Sudoku puzzle:" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            std::cin >> grid[i][j];


std::cout << "Sodoku Puzzle: \n";
printSodoku(grid);
std::cout << "\n Solution: \n";

if (SolveSudoku(grid) == true)
    printSodoku(grid);
else
    printf("No solution exists");
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code allows that, as cin takes what is before any spaces, outputs that into your code, and waits for another cin and outputs the next thing.  So, without any modification, your program should be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a getline to capture cin stream until a line break and iterate over the contained values specifying a space as the separator. You'll need to handle the indices for the grid yourself as the loop will be over the input instead of the

```
std::string value;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
while(std::getline(std::cin, value, " ")){

    grid[i][j] = atoi(value.c_string());
    if(j == 9){
        i++;
        j = 0;
    }
    else {
        j++;
    }
}
```

this assumes well behaved input (all 81 entries are in the correct order on the same line and are seperated by spaces), and that all values in the line can be converted to an int. If that's not the case you'll need to add extra code to check for those cases in the while loop.